# Zendframework 2 ResultSet to array

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I´m trying to create a dynamic list of checkboxes. I get the list of checkboxes by selecting them from my database. But now i get the error that i cannot use this list because of type ResultSet and not Array. How can I do this? Heres my code(I´m totally aware that its not good code)

my function for fetching and passing to the view

```
public function indexAction(){
    $adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $input = new SearchModel($adapter);
    $rowset = $input->getName();
    $form = new SearchForm($rowset['name']);
    $model = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'input' => $rowset));
    $model->setTemplate('search/index');
    return $model;
}
```

My model action

```
public function getName(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM benutzer";
    $rowset = $this->adapter->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    return $rowset;
}
```

And my Form

```
  public function __construct($name = null){    
$this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox',
                'name' => 'name', 
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Sportart',
                    'value_options' => $name,  
                ),
        ));
}
```

Comment: you can do in your model: $rowset->toArray();

Answer (score 0):

```
$rowset = $input->getName();
$name = '';
if ($rowset->count() > 0) {
    $name = $rowset->current()->name;
}
$form = new SearchForm($name);
```

or

```
$rowset = $input->getName()->toArray();
$name = '';
if (isset($rowset[0]['name'])) {
    $name = $rowset[0]['name'];
}
$form = new SearchForm($name);
```